# Valid syntax in both Python 2.x and 3.x for raising exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-2.x

How can I port this code to Python 3 so that it would run in both, Python 2 and Python3?

```
raise BarException, BarException(e), sys.exc_info()[2]
```

(copied from http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/08/03/the-most-underrated-feature-in-python-3/)

**Bonus question**
Does it make sense to do something like

```
IS_PYTHON2 = sys.version_info < (3, 0)

if IS_PYTHON2:
    raise BarException, BarException(e), sys.exc_info()[2]
    # replace with the code that would run in Python 2 and Python 3 respectively
else:
    raise BarException("Bar is closed on Christmas")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to resort to using `exec()` because you cannot use the 3-argument syntax in Python 3; it'll raise a syntax error.

As always the [`six` library](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) already has you covered, ported to not depend on other `six` definitions their version looks like this:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    def reraise(tp, value, tb=None):
        if value is None:
            value = tp()
        if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
            raise value.with_traceback(tb)
        raise value

else:    
    exec("def reraise(tp, value, tb=None):\n    raise tp, value, tb\n")
```

Now you can use:

```
reraise(BarException, BarException(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

without further testing for a Python version.

Comment: This looks like a brilliant answer. I did some research myself and just found a solution to do it like this: `raise ConnectionError(BarException(e)).with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])` (taken from here: http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#raise) is this bad style?

Comment: @speendo: Python 2 exceptions don't have the `with_traceback()` method, so you can't use that in polyglot code.

Comment: The page you are referring to only shows what happens when using the `2to3` tool to port Python 2 to Python 3 code, it doesn't tell you how to write code that works in both versions.

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2 / 3 compatible code to raise an exception

> Six provides simple utilities for wrapping over differences between
>   Python 2 and Python 3. It is intended to support codebases that work
>   on both Python 2 and 3 without modification. six consists of only one
>   Python file, so it is painless to copy into a project.
>   http://pythonhosted.org/six/

```
from six import reraise as raise_  # or from future.utils import raise_
traceback = sys.exc_info()[2]
err_msg = "Bar is closed on Christmas"
raise_(ValueError, err_msg, traceback)
```

## Conversion from Python 2 to Python 3.

You can make a Python 3 copy of the code using 2to3.

> 2to3 is a Python program that reads Python 2.x source code and applies
>   a series of fixers to transform it into valid Python 3.x code. The
>   standard library contains a rich set of fixers that will handle almost
>   all code. 2to3 supporting library lib2to3 is, however, a flexible and
>   generic library, so it is possible to write your own fixers for 2to3.
>   lib2to3 could also be adapted to custom applications in which Python
>   code needs to be edited automatically.
>
> ...
>
> 2to3 can also write the needed modifications right back to the source
>   file. (Of course, a backup of the original is also be made unless -n
>   is also given.) Writing the changes back is enabled with the -w flag:
>
> ```
> $ 2to3 -w example.py
> ```
>
> (from https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html)

### Python version determination

If you want to determine the python version, I recommend:

```
PY2 = sys.version_info.major == 2
PY3 = sys.version_info.major == 3
# or
import six  # Python 2 / 3 compatability module
six.PY2     # is this Python 2
six.PY3     # is this Python 3
```

### Python decisions based on version

Don't forget that early versions of Python 2 will vary from 2.7.  I like to plan for all contingencies, so the following code takes exception (litteraly) if a Python version prior to 2.7 is used.

```
# If you want to use and if/then/else block...
import sys
major = sys.version_info.major
minor = sys.version_info.minor
if major == 3:     # Python 3 exception handling
    print("Do something with Python {}.{} code.".format(major, minor))
elif major == 2:   # Python 2 exception handling
    if minor >= 7:     # Python 2.7
        print("Do something with Python {}.{} code.".format(major, minor))
    else:   # Python 2.6 and earlier exception handling
        assert minor >= 2, "Please use Python 2.7 or later, not {}.{}.".format(major,minor)
else:
    assert major >= 2, "Sorry, I'm not writing code for pre-version 2 Python.  It just ain't happening.  You are using Python {}.{}.".format(major,minor)
    assert major > 3, "I can't handle Python versions that haven't been written yet..  You are using Python {}.{}.".format(major,minor)
```

## Exception Handling in Python 2 and 3

> python-future is the missing compatibility layer between Python 2 and
>   Python 3. It allows you to use a single, clean Python 3.x-compatible
>   codebase to support both Python 2 and Python 3 with minimal overhead.
>
> It provides future and past packages with backports and forward ports
>   of features from Python 3 and 2. It also comes with futurize and
>   pasteurize, customized 2to3-based scripts that helps you to convert
>   either Py2 or Py3 code easily to support both Python 2 and 3 in a
>   single clean Py3-style codebase, module by module.
>   http://python-future.org/overview.html

See python's future module documentation at http://python-future.org/. 
Below is a copy of the Raising Excettions and Cathcing Exceptions portions of the page.

### [Raising Exceptions](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html?highlight=exception#raising-exceptions)

```
import future        # pip install future
import builtins      # pip install future
import past          # pip install future
import six           # pip install six
```

#### Python 2 only:

```
raise ValueError, "dodgy value"
```

#### Python 2 and 3:

```
raise ValueError("dodgy value")
Raising exceptions with a traceback:
```

#### Python 2 only:

```
traceback = sys.exc_info()[2]
raise ValueError, "dodgy value", traceback
```

#### Python 3 only:

```
raise ValueError("dodgy value").with_traceback()
```

#### Python 2 and 3: option 1

```
from six import reraise as raise_
# or
from future.utils import raise_

traceback = sys.exc_info()[2]
raise_(ValueError, "dodgy value", traceback)
```

#### Python 2 and 3: option 2

```
from future.utils import raise_with_traceback

raise_with_traceback(ValueError("dodgy value"))
Exception chaining (PEP 3134):
```

#### Setup:

```
class DatabaseError(Exception):
    pass
```

#### Python 3 only

```
class FileDatabase:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        try:
            self.file = open(filename)
        except IOError as exc:
            raise DatabaseError('failed to open') from exc
```

#### Python 2 and 3:

```
from future.utils import raise_from

class FileDatabase:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        try:
            self.file = open(filename)
        except IOError as exc:
            raise_from(DatabaseError('failed to open'), exc)
```

#### Testing the above:

```
try:
    fd = FileDatabase('non_existent_file.txt')
except Exception as e:
    assert isinstance(e.__cause__, IOError)    # FileNotFoundError on Py3.3+ inherits from IOError
```

### [Catching exceptions](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html?highlight=exception#catching-exceptions)

#### Python 2 only:

```
try:
    ...
except ValueError, e:
    ...
```

#### Python 2 and 3:

```
try:
    ...
except ValueError as e:
    ...
```