# Catch Broken Pipe in Python 2 AND Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-2.x

I try to write some code to catch a Broken Pipe Error. The code should run in Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

In Python 2.x a broken pipe is represented by a `socket.error`

```
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

This was changed in Python 3.x - a broken pipe now is a `BrokenPipeError`

```
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Also the syntax of exception handling has changed a bit (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463112/263589) so what I need to do would be something like:

```
try:
    do_something()
except BrokenPipeError as e: # implies Python 3.x
    resolve_for_python2()
except socket.error as e:
    if sys.version_info[0] == 2: # this is necessary, as in Python >=3.3
                                 # socket.error is an alias of OSError
                                 # https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.error
        resolve_for_python3()
    else:
        raise
```

There's (at least) one remaining problem: In Python 2.x there is no `BrokenPipeError`, so whenever there is an exception in `do_something()` Python 2.x would throw another exception and complain that it doesn't know `BrokenPipeError`. As `socket.error` is deprecated in Python 3.x a similar problem could arise in Python 3.x in the near future.

What can I do to make this code run in Python 2.x and Python 3.x?

Comment: Have a look at http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html, they show exception handling.

Comment: http://newbebweb.blogspot.in/2012/02/python-head-ioerror-errno-32-broken.html here is

Comment: Thank you! But http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#catching-exceptions doesn't explain how to catch an exception that doesn't exist in either Python 2 or Python 3 but is mandatory in the other version.

Comment: @RajarshiDas this is interesting! Are you trying to say that catching the broken pipe isn't necessary at all if Python is advised to just ignore the SIGPIPE error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If all you care about are broken pipe errors, then you might want to catch `socket.error` and simply check whether it's indeed a broken pipe error.

You can do so using the exception's `errno` attribute, which is present in both Python 2 and Python 3, which means, you don't need different Python 2 vs. 3 logic (I'd argue the intent is a little clearer this way):

```
import socket
import errno


try:
    do_something()
except socket.error as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EPIPE:
        # Not a broken pipe
        raise
    do_something_about_the_broken_pipe()
```

---

If you do care about more than broken pipes, thefourtheye's answer is appropriate and idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you! It worries me a bit that `socket.error` is deprecated in Python 3. So in case I update my Python 3 interpreter, there might be another problem in the (near) future...

Comment: @speendo there are dozens of references to `socket.error` *in the Python standard library itself*. It's deprecated, sure, but it's not going away. Removing `socket.error` would be a pointless breaking change, which is something the Python core developers have publicly stated they'll avoid in the future. If it did end up removed (in a few decades?! ;) ), the error would be trivial to identify and fix, and at that point you probably wouldn't be supporting Python 2 anymore anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using `BrokenPipeError` and if it throws a `NameError`, then fall back to `socket.error`, like this

```
import socket
try:
    expected_error = BrokenPipeError
except NameError:
    expected_error = socket.error
```

And then use it like this

```
try:
    1 == 2
except expected_error as ex:
    # Handle the actual exception here
```