# Are 'raise a,b,c,' and 'raise (a,b,c)' same in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

Can somebody please explain if why or why not 'raise a,b,c,' and 'raise (a,b,c)' are same in Python 2.7.

I tried to find information on how Tuples are treated from [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-raise_stmt) and [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3109/) but I couldn't establish if I could use the above expressions in place of one another.

Here is some background.
I have a Python 2 code which is having a lot of following statements

```
raise e,v,t
```

Python 3 gives error on this syntax. 
Converting it to following gets away the Python 3 compiler error but I wanted to verify if intent remains same in both Python 2 as well as Python 3.

```
raise (e,v,t)
```

Comment: Did you try them? Did you get the same result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463087/raise-exception-in-python-2-x-and-3-x/40877934 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497013/convert-code-from-python-2-x-to-3-x/5497070

Comment: Did you try to check the Python3 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-raise_stmt)?

Comment: @AChampion : I tried `x = 1,2,3` and `x =(1,2,3)` in python interpreter and got 'type(x)' as same that's why I had confusion if it is a safe change.

Comment: In other words, no it is not the same. In fact in Python 3 if you ever execute that line, you'll get an error, because it will try to call that instance (which is a tuple), and you can only `raise` objects that derive from `BaseException`

Answer (score 1):

`raise` has *never* taken a tuple as a parameter. In Python 2, the syntax was such that it *looked* like a tuple, which is where your confusion is coming from. There was a drastic syntax change for Python 3, where the redundant exception class type was removed and the keyword `from` is used in place of a comma.

In Python 2:

```
raise a, b, c
```

Becomes in Python 3:

```
raise b.with_traceback(c)
```

Comment: You've gotten the exception chaining syntax mixed up with the syntax for alternate tracebacks. The way to pick a different traceback is the [`with_traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.with_traceback) method, so it's `raise a(b).with_traceback(c)`, or `raise b.with_traceback(c)` if `b` is already an instance of `a` (or one of a few other variants, because Python 2 has a lot of ways to interpret the second `raise` argument). [`from` is for one exception being caused by another](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement).

Comment: @user2357112 thanks, I was misreading the documentation. I've never actually tried raising anything other than a simple `Exception` class myself.

Answer (score 1):

Never pass a tuple to `raise`. It won't do what you expect.

On both Python 2 and Python 3, `raise` is documented to not accept a tuple. However, Python 2 has a [weird code path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/ceval.c#L3846) in the `raise` implementation where if the first (or only) argument to `raise` is a tuple, it will be repeatedly replaced with its first element until Python reaches something that isn't a tuple. I have no idea why this is a thing, but it means that something like

```
raise ((Exception,), "other", "tuple", "items", "get", "ignored")
```

gets treated like

```
raise Exception
```

Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/lmNOWm). Python 3 behaves [more sensibly](http://ideone.com/e2ADfD), erroring out because a tuple isn't an exception.

---

The syntax for raising exceptions changed on Python 3. The Python 2 statement

```
raise ExceptionType, value, traceback
```

is now

```
raise ExceptionType(value).with_traceback(traceback)
```

or, if `value` is an instance of `ExceptionType`,

```
raise value.with_traceback(traceback)
```

Unfortunately, these syntaxes are incompatible to the degree that you can't even write both and pick which one to run based on your Python version. You'll get a syntax error before your code even runs.

---

The easiest way to fix this is with a compatibility library. For example, with [`six.reraise`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/index.html#six.reraise):

```
six.reraise(ExceptionType, value, traceback)
```